# Where is MathML in MathNet.Symbolics for c#?

Tags: c#, mathml, math.net, mathnet-numerics, mathdotnet-symbolics

[Here it is](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics/blob/722834e73f674e8ce1d89a1848c29df1f0e91c9e/src/Symbolics/Convert/MathML.fs) for F#; [Here it is](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics/blob/master/src/SymbolicsUnitTests/Tests.fs#L305) in UnitTests. So it shall be at least in F# distribution thus in .net dll. And yet it does not show itself in Assembly Explorer
[image]

How to use MathNet.Symbolics MathML classes in CSharp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathML has only recently been added and is not part of any release yet. I plan to do a new release within the next couple days.

*Update: has been released in the meantime in [v0.9.0](http://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/ReleaseNotes.html#0-9-0-2016-03-14).*